# How do I add a Clothing model to an unclothed model?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, import

So im trying to make a 2d game where the characters and graphics are 2d 'sprites' but i render them with blender. 
I have a model of a man with no clothes and then a model of a windbreaker fitted to the man and the windbreaker is already fully done with the vertex weights and armature setup to the armature of the man so if i move the mans left arm up the windbreakers left arm moves up with him.
Now im trying to make the animations on the unclothed base model, and render them, then for example import the windbreaker i made into the blender scene so i can render the exact same animations but with the windbreaker instead. How do i do this? I tried some appending, some linking and exporting FBX + importing the windbreaker and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out now

STEP 1
Unlink clothing from model
STEP 2 
If its bigger and above the model, set x y z scales to .2525
Step 3
Append the object and parent it to main mesh with "Armature Deform" option, none of the ones below. ( Thats because i already weight painted the windbreaker )